# Ratio problem solving- ten machines use 200 kW

Tags: fractions, ratio

Ten machines use 200 kilowatts to operate for 5 days, 10 hours per day. Determine the number of kilowatts used if they work for 3 days, 8 hours per day?

and the answer has to be in kW

updated

would it be

200kw /130hrs = x/80hrs

1600/130 = 130x

123= x

---

I did fractions with cross multiplying and got x= 71.4 kW but I know I am wrong.

5/3 + 10/8 = 200 kW/ x

40/24 + 30/42 = 200kW/ x

70/24 = 200kW/ x

70x = 5000 kW/70

x= 71.4 kW

Comment: Could you describe in words what your first equation is saying? I think you're overcomplicating the problem.

Comment: @bounceback- the question just says "ten machines use 200 kilowatts to operate for 5 days, 10 hours per day. Determine the number of kilowatts used if they work for 3 days, 8 hours per day?"

Comment: So why have you divided 5 by 3 and added 10 divided by 8?

Comment: $200$ KW used for $50$ hours $(5 \times 10)$ of operation, so how many KW used for $24$ hours of operation $(3 \times 8)$? Number of machines is immaterial as they are same in both cases.

Comment: @bounceback because they gave me 3 days and 5 days so i divided it... i know i am wrong :(

Answer (score 3):

The unit of energy is the kilowatt-hour or some such.  Kilowatts are a measure of power.  As such, the duration of operation does not matter.  If ten machines use $200$ kW, they use $200$ kW no matter how long they run.  It is possible the point of the problem is for you to notice the difference between kilowatts and kilowatt-hours.

If the problem means $200$ kWh for $10$ machines, $5$ days, $10$ hours/day, that is $50$ hours of operation, so a $4$ kW power level.  $3$ days, $8$ hours/day is $24$ hours, so they would consume $96$ kWh.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to say.